# How long will a non-clearing notification stay?

Tags: android

If my app fires a notification and marks it as non-clearing (i.e. tapping it does not remove it), what will result in the notification being removed?

Would I be right in assuming that if the app is shut down by the memory manager that this will cause the notification will be removed? Or will the notification persist even if the app is recycled?

My app needs to show a persistent notification, and I need to understand whether I can set it up in the app, or if I need to build a service to manage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start a notification with the `FLAG_NO_CLEAR` it will persist until you cancel it in the `NotificationManager` with a call to `NotificationManager.cancel(int notificiationId)`

I'm not sure what would happen to the notification if your app were uninstalled, although I suspect it would be cleared then too.  That said it should be really easy to test. Create an activity that creates a notification. Then close it, kill it, uninstall it, etc... and see what happens.

Comment: If I "force stop" my app through program manager or some kind of task killer - the notification icon immediately disappears from the notification bar, even if the `FLAG_NO_CLEAR` is set. In other cases I have not noticed that the icon is removed ever

Comment: I think the uninstall will remove the icon too. At least because after uninstall there will not be the application which is related (responsible) to this notification.

Comment: is your question answered then?

Comment: The icon is certainly removed on uninstall and kill, but the scenario I am asking about is re memory management, which isn't so easy to test, hence asking the question.